# Python - Faster way of making a custom list of text in a file

Tags: python, performance, list, time

I'm trying to make a list of text in a text file like it was being typed.. Kinda like this:

```
T
Te
Tex
Text
```

I dunno how to explain it well, so here's an example:

Text file contents:

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
```

The list of the **first** line will be like: `['L', 'Li', 'Lin', 'Line', 'Line ', 'Line 1', 'Line 1\n']`.

And the **complete** list will be: `[['L', 'Li', 'Lin', 'Line', 'Line ', 'Line 1', 'Line 1\n'], ['L', 'Li', 'Lin', 'Line', 'Line ', 'Line 2', 'Line 2\n'], ['L', 'Li', 'Lin', 'Line', 'Line ', 'Line 3']]`

This is my current code:

```
lines=open('foo.txt', 'r').readlines()
letters=[]
cnt=0
for line in lines:
    letters.append([])
    for letter in line:
        if len(letters[cnt]) > 0:
            letters[cnt].append(letters[cnt][len(letters[cnt])-1]+letter)
        else:
            letters[cnt].append(letter)
    cnt+=1

print letters
```

The output is exactly like the **complete** list above.

The problem is this code is kinda slow on bigger files.. Is there any faster way to achieve the same output?

Comment: Execution time: 4.00600004196 seconds (without printing) on a 4.15 MB text file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a `list comprehension`:

```
In [66]: with open("data.txt") as f:
    print [[line[0:i+1] for i in range(len(line))] for line in f]
   ....:     
[['L', 'Li', 'Lin', 'Line', 'Line ', 'Line 1', 'Line 1\n'], 
 ['L', 'Li', 'Lin', 'Line', 'Line ', 'Line 2', 'Line 2\n'],
 ['L', 'Li', 'Lin', 'Line', 'Line ', 'Line 3', 'Line 3\n']]
```

Comment: Execution time: 1.50900006294 seconds (without printing) on a 4.15 MB text file

Comment: @UltimateZero paste the print line after `f:` and it is a one-liner. Also it is better than something like : `result.append([line[:i+1] for i in xrange(len(line))])`, which is slower compared to list comprehensions.

Comment: What is `In [66]:`? I'm still a novice Pythoner, and this doesn't compute, nor run. I get `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`. If I remove that it works. Just wonderin'... Still gets my vote.

Comment: @IanAtkin I am using IPython interpreter, it uses `In[#]` and `Out[#]` instead of `>>>` used in normal python interpreter.

Answer (score 3):

```
result = []
for line in open('foo.txt'):
    result.append([line[:i+1] for i in xrange(len(line))])
print result
```

Comment: Execution time: 1.51699995995 seconds (without printing) on a 4.15 MB text file

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a particularly good case for Python's memoryviews: when using them you do not creates substrings of the original string, merely *views* of the original string. The performance gain on a large file with lines longer than few characters should be substantial.

```
results = []
with open("data.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        letters = tuple(buffer(line, 0, i+1) for i in xrange(len(line)))
        results.append(letters)
```

If list of all prefixes do not need to be all expanded at the same time, using generators can be considered.

Note:
If timing without printing, the following should be hard to beat ;-)

```
with open("data.txt") as f:
    results = (buffer(line, 0, i+1) for line in f for i in xrange(len(line)))
```

Comment: Syntax error in 4th line.. And do you mean `results = []` in the first line?

Comment: The error was because of missing () around the generator. I simplified the example by taking the generator out.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why this gets slow is because you collect huge lists with only redundant information. Do you really need these lists or would something like that do the trick, too?

```
for line in lines:
    for i in range (0,len(line)-1):
        for j,letter in enumerate(line):
            print letter,
            if j>=i:
                print ''
                break
```

This outputs

```
T 
T h 
T h i 
T h i s 
T h i s   
T h i s   i 
T h i s   i s 
T h i s   i s   
T h i s   i s   t 
T h i s   i s   t h 
T h i s   i s   t h e 
T h i s   i s   t h e   
T h i s   i s   t h e   f 
T h i s   i s   t h e   f i 
T h i s   i s   t h e   f i r 
T h i s   i s   t h e   f i r s 
T h i s   i s   t h e   f i r s t 
T h i s   i s   t h e   f i r s t   
T h i s   i s   t h e   f i r s t   l 
T h i s   i s   t h e   f i r s t   l i 
T h i s   i s   t h e   f i r s t   l i n 
T h i s   i s   t h e   f i r s t   l i n e
```

and I assume this is what you want (except for the whitespaces between the letters but I assume we can get rid of them somehow, too).